# Search list with Java Stream using multiple filters

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List of Java Objects (assume getters and setters):

```
Record(String name, String part, String value);
```

I need to return a boolean for if the list contains a certain `name` value and a certain `part` value.

I have it working for one filter at a time:

```
//assume records are added to this list
List<Record> masterList = new ArrayList<Record>();

boolean check = masterList.stream().map(Record::getName).filter(record.getName()::equals).findFirst().isPresent();
```

But I get error `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context` on `Record::getPart` for this attempt:

```
masterList.stream().map(Record::getName).filter(record.getName()::equals).map(Record::getPart).filter(record.getPart()::equals).findFirst().isPresent();
```

Comment: It's worth noting that whenever you do `filter` + `findFirst` + `isPresent` it can be simplified to `anyMatch(e -> criteria...)`

Comment: I've reopened. You can't back out of a stream once you've already `map`'ed it. Just don't perform a `map`, consider each `Record` instead and have a more complex `filter` lambda expression that evaluates each.

Comment: I didn't say to change your code to using `anyMatch` as now you're using it incorrectly... I was just saying that "it's worth noting".

Comment: *"if the list contains a certain `name` value and a certain `part` value"* Does it have to be the same Record that has both values? Or can it be one Record matching `name`, and another Record matching `part`?

Comment: @Andreas has to have both values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is just not possible i.e. when you perform `map(Record::getName)` you have a `Stream<String>` where all the strings are the record names and any chained method calls after that is based only upon the record names.

instead just use a single `filter`:

```
boolean check = masterList.stream()
                           .filter(s -> s.getName().equals(record.getName()) &&
                                        s.getPart().equals(record.getPart()))
                           .findFirst().isPresent();
```

or better use `anyMatch`

```
boolean check = masterList.stream()
                         .anyMatch(s -> s.getName().equals(record.getName()) &&
                                    s.getPart().equals(record.getPart()));
```

**Edit:**

if it can be one record matching name, and another record matching part?

Then you can collect all the record names and parts into a set as follows:

```
Set<String> container = masterList.stream()
                                  .flatMap(r -> Stream.of(r.getName(), r.getPart()))
                                  .collect(toSet());
```

Then do:

```
boolean result = container.contains(record.getName()) && 
                 container.contains(record.getPart()) ;
```

Comment: You're assuming a Yes to the first part of my [clarification question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138418/search-list-with-java-stream-using-multiple-filters#comment95108492_54138418).

Comment: I think you mean `getPart()` instead of `getValue()`.

Comment: @shmosel as for "The second solution can fail if name and part are the same." _if that is a possible scenario in their design_ then one can go for --> `masterList.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getName().equals(record.getName())) &&
                          masterList.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getPart().equals(record.getPart()));`